# Flutter ListView rotary

Tags: flutter

I am relatively new to Flutter, and I want to design a ListView that can be rotated. For example, in the first image we have 12 static items:

[image: Rotary list]

But when there are more than 12 items, I want the user to be able to scroll on the same wheel and see the hidden items, and at the same time hide the remaining items:

[image: Rotary list after rotation]

In the example, you can see that if the user scrolls, the first 2 items are hidden to show item number 13 and 14. I have investigated for more than a week and have tried different packages, but to date I have not found a solution. I thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomScrollView with a SliverPersistentHeader to create the curved effect. Inside this, you can use a Transform widget to rotate the items accordingly based on the scroll position.